# How to solve this integral with exponent depending on two independent variables?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, integration

The question is I was given the *Hamiltonian* of two classical particles with masses $m$ with which I must calculate *Partition function*
$$H =\frac{P_1^2}{2m} +\frac{P_2^2}{2m} + q_1^2 + q_2^2 +\frac{q_1q_2}{4}$$

To calculate *Partition function*
$$Z = \int^∞_{-∞}  \exp\left[ -\beta\left(\frac{P_1^2}{2m} +\frac{P_2^2}{2m} + q_1^2 + q_2^2 +\frac{q_1q_2}{4}\right) \right] dp_1 dp_2 dq_1 dq_2$$
I cn see that the first two terms of the *Hamiltonian* in the integral can be calculated by the basic integrals formula involving gamma functions but the last three terms of the *Hamiltonian* challenges me.
help me solve this!

Answer (score 1):

The two integrals over the momentum are Gaussian
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\beta{p^2\over 2m}}dp
   =\big(2\pi mk_BT\big)^{1/2}$$
The two integrals over $q_1$ and $q_2$ can be computed separately. Let us try to introduce the change of variable
$$q_3=q_2+\alpha q_1$$
Since $q_3^2=q_2^2+\alpha_2^2q_1^2+2\alpha q_1q_2$, we see that the integrals are decoupled when choosing $\alpha=1/8$. The determinant of the Jacobian is $1$ so the integral becomes
$$\eqalign{
\int e^{-\beta(q_1^2+q_2^2+{1\over 4}q_1q_2)}dq_1dq_2
&=\int e^{-\beta(q_1^2+q_3^2-\alpha^2q_1^2)}dq_1dq_3   \cr
&=\int e^{-\beta(1-\alpha^2)q_1^2}dq_1\int e^{-\beta q_3^2}dq_3\cr
&=\sqrt{\pi k_BT\over 1-\alpha^2}.\sqrt{\pi k_BT} \cr
&={k_BT\over\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}
}$$

Comment: thank you @Christophe. Why have you mentioned determinant of jacobi is 1? what does it mean?

Comment: Since Christophe changed the variable of integration, there can be change of measure. One uses Jacobian to determine how the measure should change.